# Deleting dynamically allocated array of class

Tags: c++

How to delete dynamically allocated array prod?

```
Z2* prod = new Z2[new_degree];
```

class:

```
class Z2 {
public:
    Z2() { modulo = 0; };
    Z2(short int a) { if (a > 0) modulo = a % 2; else modulo = -a % 2; };
private:
    int modulo;
```

Edit:
I can use only this:

```
<iostream>,
<sstream>,
<string>,
<cstdlib> 
<cstring>
```

Comment: `delete[] Z2;`?? (if allocated with `new[]`, use `delete[]`, otherwise just `new` and `delete`).

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `Z2(short a)` can be written much more simply as `modulo = std::abs(a) % 2;`.

Answer (score 1):

In all versions of [C++](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete), you do the following:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<Z2> prod(new_degree);
```

If for some reason you can't use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then as of C++11 there is [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)).

```
#include <memory>
auto prod = std::make_unique<Z2[]>(new_degreee);
```

Either of these completely turns management of `prod` over to C++; you no longer have to worry about when (or how) to free `prod`.

Comment: Just an example of "*some strange reason*", sometimes you intentionally do not want the objects to be default initialized (for example  `std::vector<int>` initializes everything in it to be zero if you call the constructor that takes an initial size).